# Unity2D: Muting audio Clip problems

Tags: unity, audio

I'm trying to create a mute button (that goes both way, e.g mute and un-mute) using button onclick  [image]

So far I'm not having the greatest luck. I made this:

```
  mute = !mute;
    if (mute){
        gameObject.GetComponent<Gamestartsound>().volume = 0;
    }else
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Gamestartsound>().volume = 0;
    }
```

To achieve what I'm trying to do but getting errors:

error CS0118: `UI_ManagerScripts.Gamestartsound' is a`field' but a `type' was expected

and

error CS0118: `UI_ManagerScripts.Gamestartsound' is a`field' but a `type' was expected

anyway this is my full UIManager script, I did the audio like that because I was having some issues earlier but it's better now so yeah:

```
public AudioClip Gamestartsound;
public GameObject Music;
public PlayerMovement playerMovementRef;
private bool mute;


public void DisableBoolAnimator(Animator anim)
{
    anim.SetBool ("IsDisplayed", false);
}

public void EnableBoolAnimator(Animator anim)
{
    anim.SetBool ("IsDisplayed", true);
}

public void NavigateTo(int scene)
{
    Application.LoadLevel ("Game Level");
    Movement.Restart ();
}
public void Mute ()
{
    mute = !mute;
    if (mute){
        gameObject.GetComponent<Gamestartsound>().volume = 0;
    }else
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Gamestartsound>().volume = 0;
    }
}

public void ExitGame()
{
    Application.Quit ();
}   
public void PauseGame()
{
    Time.timeScale = 0;
    playerMovementRef.enabled = false;
}

public void UnPauseGame()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    playerMovementRef.enabled = true;
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (Gamestartsound, transform.position);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this line:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Gamestartsound>().volume = 0;
```

`Gamestartsound` is not a component, that's why it doesn't compile. I'd fix this by adding an `AudioSourceComponent` into the game object in inspector and setting its clip to whatever clip `Gamestartsound` refers. Then you can change the line into:

```
gameObject.GetComponent< AudioSource >().volume = 0;
```

You are also setting the volume to 0 in both branches:

```
if (mute){
    gameObject.GetComponent<Gamestartsound>().volume = 0;
}else
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Gamestartsound>().volume = 0;
}
```

The latter should probably be set to 1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply the Gamestartsound is used because I wanted the ausio clip to be called when I click on a button, So its only natural that if the user would want to mute that sound. So would adding a  AudioSourceComponent  work?  Would it play onAwake or play when I click a button??? Thank you :)

Comment: It has a boolean property `playOnAwake` so you can control it. Actually I misspelled the component name, it seems to be just `AudioSource`.